# How to find underlying device node of network interface using C?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

USB device can be interacted with using `ioctl()`.
I want to send `ioctl()` to USB Ethernet Adapter, but the only thing I know is network interface name.
One method is to traverse /sys/bus/usb subtree and find node with `net/<ifname>` directory, but it seems to be not so reliable.

Is there more straight method?